# Error Open Urls Selenium From txt File

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I m trying to open URLS From TXT file with selenium webdriver.But code is giving me error.Here is code that i m using with python 3.4.3.What can be the problem in this code?

```
from selenium import webdriver                
with open("vps.txt","r") as fi:              
    urls = fi.read().splitlines()                

for url in urls:                                     
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()                           
    browser.get(url)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                               
  File "C:\pselenium\browse.py", line 8, in <module>                               
    browser.get(url)                               
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 245, in get                               
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})                               
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute                               
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)                               
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response                               
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)                               
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Target URL ï»¿www.youtube.com/watch?v=DowtrQhvbUM is not well-formed.                               
Stacktrace:                               
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.get (file:///C:/Users/naV/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpja7hed7p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10636)                               
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/naV/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpja7hed7p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)                               
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/naV/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpja7hed7p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)                               
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/naV/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpja7hed7p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: Try use codecs.open() if you are sure the file contains well formed url.

Answer (score 2):

`Target URL ï»¿www.youtube.com/watch?v=DowtrQhvbUM is not well formed`

It looks like you've got a problem with your file encoding. I'm not sure if that's the BOM or not, but you should check your file with a hex editor.

Comment: Yes i think that may be problem,i used notepad to save txt file and UTF8 Format.What other editor can i use to solve that problem?

Comment: You can use the [encoding parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data) - `open('vps.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:` and that should work.

Comment: Also, get a better text editor, like Notepad++, Sublime, Vim, Emacs... ed ;)

Comment: not worked after using your code got error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
After using Notepad++ Getting Same Error. delay command error

Comment: Delay command error is not the one you posted. Apparently it's not *actually* `utf-8`, grumble grumble.

Comment: Sorry i write that error in short actually 
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/naV/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpja7hed7p/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608) 
i was calling this a delay error that i m getting.

Comment: That looks like a *new* error, and should probably be a new question (if there's not already an answer for it on SO).